# Can I use a library developed in c++11 in c++17 code?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I'm working on a c++ project and I use c++17 as c++ standard. I've some library dependencies which has been developed using c++11. Are there any obstacles in using this library? Do I need to recompile it using c++17 in order to make sure I can use it in my project? I'm using Clang as compiler in my code and the library has been compiled using g++ .

Edit: If I use g++ in both library and my code is there any obstacle in terms of different c++ standards (std11 vs std17)?

Many Thanks,

Comment: maybe, depends on what compiler you've used, whether libraries you have used have different ABIs depending on c++ version

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question with compiler information.

Comment: Just an example of incompatibility: some features, such as `std::auto_ptr`, were removed in C++17. If your library uses them (e.g., in header files), then, in theory, your library wouldn't be C++17 compatible.

Comment: Unless you find something in the documentation that indicates that your version of clang is binary compatible with the version of gcc that was used to compile the library (highly unlikely), you're out of luck.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik by default they both follow the Itanium ABI. The main source of difference is if you use a different standard library, but usually clang on linux will default to libstdc++, precisely so it can be compatible with gcc.

Answer (score 5):

In general, you should be able to use a C++11 library in C++17 code.

But, you need to remember that C++ does *not* have a standardized ABI. So the *source* may be compatible, but any pre-compiled artifacts are likely *not*.

You have *source* compatibility, not *binary* compatibility. This means that - as a rule - you *must* compile *all* parts of your project with the *exact same* compiler. You *cannot* (as a rule) re-use a library compiled with a different or older compiler with code you compile with a different (or newer) one.

But you *should* be able to compile that C++11 code with your C++17 compiler (in *most* cases - there *are* exceptions).

Comment: As a corollary, some binary libraries expose only a C ABI, even though the library may be written in some version of C++.  Those libraries ought to be able to be used with any version of C++.  The C ABI being a _lingua franca_ for C++ and many other compiled programming languages.  (This comment is for the general reader, since I already know that Jesper knows this.)

Comment: That's a very pessimistic view. First, `g++ -std=c++17` is binary compatible with `g++ -std=c++11` (same for clang). Second, both compilers try very hard to keep binary compatibility from one release to the next. Third, as long as you use the same standard library (probably libstdc++ in the OP's case), clang and gcc use the same ABI.

Comment: @MarcGlisse "That's a very pessimistic view" - I don't believe it is. Try linking objects compiled with gcc 4.x with things compiled with gcc 9.x - I bet you that I can find situations where it will just blow up. Also; try linking objects compiled with old versions of clang or visual studio to objects compiled with modern gcc. I can *easily* point you at examples where it won't work. And no, C++11 does *not* promise to be binary compatible with C++17. Please present a standards quote that proves me wrong.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's moving the goal-posts. Yes, it would be nice if all versions of all compilers on all platforms produced compatible code for all options. But neither is that realistic, nor what Marc claimed, nor needed by the OP. Anyway, those implementation-specifica are not in the language standard's purview.

Comment: Visual Studio is different, let's ignore it. If you configure gcc-9 to use the old libstdc++ ABI, it will link just fine with gcc-4.x objects. And there has been just one such new ABI since gcc-4.0. I actually wish they would break the ABI more often... Compilers can promise compatibility between C++11 and C++17, it doesn't have to come from the standard. And sure, bugs happen, but then even using a single compiler there can still be bugs (fewer maybe...).

Comment: @Deduplicator The *point* is; if you want to be *sure* that all your code works together, you *must* compile it all with the same compiler. It's the only way to be *guaranteed* that things will work.

Comment: @JesperJuhl If you use the exact same version with the exact same option you have a much higher chance than taking two arbitrary ones. Still not guaranteed though, e.g. look at the mess MSVC produced with member-pointers. But we aren't talking about arbitrary compilers, but the same one with different standards.